# Select no Hibernate não retorna classe estendida

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlet

Tenho uma classe, Fornecedor, que é estendida da classe `Pessoa`.

No método `listarFornecedores` da classe `FOrnecedorDao`:

```
public List<Fornecedor> listarFornecedores() {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores = new ArrayList<Fornecedor>();
    query = session.createQuery("FROM Fornecedor");
    listaFornecedores = query.list();
    session.close();
    return listaFornecedores;

    }
```

o resultado é:

> [Pessoa [id=1, nome=123, telefone=123, endereco=123,
>   numeroDoEndereco=123, cep=123, bairro=123, cidade=123, estado=123,
>   email=123]]

Ao rodar o *servlet*:

```
protected void buscar(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

try{
List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores = new FornecedorDao().listarFornecedores();

Integer i = 0;
Fornecedor f = new Fornecedor();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

while ( i < listaFornecedores.size() ) {
    f.setid(listaFornecedores.get(i).getid());
    f.setInicioAtividades(listaFornecedores.get(i).getInicioAtividades());  
        String data1 =  sdf.format(f.getInicioAtividades());
        System.out.println(listaFornecedores);
        //System.out.println(data1);
        //System.out.println(f.getInicioFormatado());

        i=i+1;
    }
```

Ou seja, ele só retorna as variaveis da classe Pessoa, e nada da classe Fornecedor... porém no no jsp sai certo....

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Classe Pessoa:

```
public abstract class Pessoa implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column
private Integer id;
@Column
private String nome;
@Column
private String telefone;
@Column
private String endereco;
@Column
private String numeroDoEndereco;
@Column
private String cep;
@Column
private String bairro;
@Column 
private String cidade;
@Column
private String estado;
@Column
private String email;
// resto do código omitido
```

Classe Fornecedor:

```
public class Fornecedor extends Pessoa{

    @Column
    private Integer codigo;
    @Column
    private String pessoaContato;
    @Column
    private String cnpj;
    @Column
    private Date inicioAtividades;
    /*Getters and Setters*/
}
```

Será que alguém consegue me dar uma luz, me explicar pq isso acontece, e como devemos fazer pra pegar também os valores também da classe fornecedor?

Comment: Voce colocou as annotations- @Entity
@Table(name="Fornecedor") - em qual classe?

Comment: Na classe Fornecedor.

Comment: Você implementou o método `toString()` na classe `Fornecedor` e o anotou com `@Override`?

Comment: Kra, realmente o problema estava no toString()! Estava sem na classe Fornecedor, aí adicionei na classe Fornecedor o seguinte: @Override
 public String toString() {
  
  return super.toString() + "Fornecedor [codigo=" + codigo + ", pessoaContato=" + pessoaContato + ", cnpj=" + cnpj
    + ", inicioAtividades=" + inicioAtividades + "]";
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o problema é que eu tinha esquecido o toString da classe Fornecedor, apenas inseri na classe Pessoa.

Então, na classe fornecedor, fiz assim:

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    return super.toString() + "Fornecedor [codigo=" + codigo + ", pessoaContato=" + pessoaContato + ", cnpj=" + cnpj
            + ", inicioAtividades=" + inicioAtividades + "]";
}
```

O resultado ficou:

> [Pessoa [id=1, nome=123, telefone=123, endereco=123, numeroDoEndereco=123, cep=123, bairro=123, cidade=123, estado=123, email=123]Fornecedor [codigo=123, pessoaContato=123, cnpj=123, inicioAtividades=1986-04-30 16:15:44.0]]

Agradeço ao amigo @Felipe Marinho que iluminou minha mente :)

Answer (score 0):

As duas classes terão a `annotation` `Entity`.
No entanto, a classe pai deve ter uma `annotation` extra indicando qual será a estratégia de herança utilizada.

Por exemplo, você pode querer que para cada *sub-classe* seja criado uma tabela, então, você utilizará:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Pessoa implements Serializable {
}
```

Você pode ler mais sobre a `annotation` `@Inheritance` neste [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168).

Comment: Bom dia :)! mas já está com essa anotação. @Entity
@Table(name = "pessoa")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Pessoa implements Serializable{